# JavaScript does not detect anime js

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, anime.js

Im learning animations and JS, I've decide that to go with anime.js. Though when i try to do a basic function I get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: anime is not defined" error.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Underscores</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="backend.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.js"></script>

  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
  <div class="box green"></div>
  <div class="box yellow"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: inline-block;

}

.red{background-color: red;}

.blue{background-color: blue;}

.green{background-color: green;}

.yellow{background-color: yellow;}
```

JS:

```
anime({
   targets: 'div.box.red',
   translateY: [
     { value: 200, duration: 500 },
     { value: 0, duration: 800 }
   ],
   rotate:{
     value: '1turn',
     easing: 'easeInOutSine'
   }
});
```

Comment: Try including the dependency *before* your main script. If you try to load the dependency afterwards, the main script will break because its dependency has not been loaded yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As CertainPerformance said, the dependency of anime.js must be declared before backend.js which is the one using it. Like This:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.js"></script>
<script src="backend.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Hope this clarifications solves your problem!

Comment: yea that works but it does not animate, would to happen to know why that is?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried different things including the suggested I downloaded the zip file and tried to use it and its telling me is not defined `<script src="JavaScript/anime-master/lib/anime.es.js"></script><script src ="JavaScript/userform.js"></script>` I've also tried `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.0.1/lib/anime.min.js"></script>` and still telling me is not defined

On my Javascript file, i'm trying to use the anime like this`anime({ targets: '#RegistrationForm', translatex: 250 });` I also tried with a variable, and class I'm trying to animate a form`<form method="POST" action="RegistrationSend.php" id="RegistrationForm" > <div class="card d-flex justify-content-center" style= "width: 30rem;"> <div class="card-body">` i've also tried the card-body class and still no success it always tell me the anime is not defined. any advise?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The format here is a little different from forums. So here is a little onboarding help. SO will likely delete your response because it is not an "Answer" to the OP's question. You can post a new question, referencing this one, or add a bounty to this one if you have reputation, or you can post a specific question as a "Comment" to a particular post. Please read more in the help section, linked to at the top of every page.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31514103)

Answer (score -1):

Try to load both script before body gets over.
It worked for me.
Hope it would do same for you.